# SignalR/Owin self host - switching ports

Tags: c#, signalr, owin, self-hosting, signalr.client

My application is a service/client which uses SignalR for communication. I am trying to implement scenario, where SignalR server gracefully switches to another port. Here's how server gets created or switched:

```
    public void StartListen(int port)
    {
        StopListen();

        var url = string.Format("http://localhost:{0}/test1", port);

        webApp = WebApp.Start(url, app =>
        {
            app.MapSignalR<Endpoint>("/endpoint");
        });

        Log("Listening on {0}", url);
    }

    public void StopListen()
    {
        if (webApp != null)
        {
            webApp.Dispose();
            webApp = null;
        }
    }

    public void Pong()
    {
        var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetConnectionContext<Endpoint>();
        context.Connection.Broadcast("pong");
    }
```

Where endpoint is:

```
public class Endpoint : PersistentConnection
{
    protected override Task OnReceived(IRequest r, string connectionId, string data)
    {
        return Task.Run(() => Host.Log("Got: {0}", data));
    }
}
```

I also have a client object which switches connection to a new port, like this:

```
    Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Connection connection;

    public void StartConnection(int port)
    {
        StopConnection();

        var url = string.Format("http://localhost:{0}/test1/endpoint", port);
        connection = new Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.Connection(url);
        connection.Start().ContinueWith(task => Log("Connected"));
    }

    public void StopConnection()
    {
        if (connection != null)
        {
            connection.Stop();
            connection.Dispose();
            connection = null;

            Log("stopped");
        }
    }

    private void ConnectionReceivedHandler(string obj)
    {
        Log("Got: {0}", obj);
    }

    public void Ping()
    {
        connection.Send("ping");
    }
```

Is that a correct implementation? The reason I'm asking is that following sequence of actions leads to snafu:

- Start Listening on port 4080
- Client connect to port 4080 (ping/pong works)
- Client disconnects
- Start listening on port 4081
- Client cannot connect

However, following sequence works fine:

- Start Listening on port 4080
- Start listening on port 4081
- Client connect to port 4081 (ping/pong works)

I have a suspicion I'm not doing something I was required to do in order for that shenanigan to work

Comment: You'll want to use a custom dependency resolver and completely avoid GobalHost when you're self hosting. Also Connection Stop and Dispose are the same thing.

Comment: Could you elaborate as to what exactly does that mean? Any URL that has an example? Also, if you could please post it as "answer", I would then be able to give you rep.